# Command to identify if a NODE is a SEED

Tags: cassandra, datastax

To quickly identify in a 3-nodes Cassandra cluster (5-nodes in Production environment) if a NODE is a SEED, I came with the following :

`if grep "^\s*- seeds: .*$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1).*$" /etc/*/*/cassandra.yaml > /dev/null
    then echo "It is a SEED."
else 
    echo "It is not a SEED."
fi`

, which does good as a one-liner :

`if grep "^\s*- seeds: .*$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1).*$" /etc/*/*/cassandra.yaml > /dev/null ; then echo "It is a SEED." ;else echo "It is not a SEED."; f`

In my case, i have both versions, Datastax and Community Edition, in my perimeter, hence the *curious subtree* I use to find cassandra.yaml.

Is there a better/cleaner/quickier way ?

Comment: Why you are trying to identify a seed node?

Comment: As it was explained to me, a Cassandra cluster which consists of 2 SEEDs plus x NODEs, has to be started in a specific order (SEEDs first), to ensure that Gossiping will work.

Comment: What @dilsingi said.  Who cares?

Comment: Let me qualify that.  Seed nodes are only relevant within the context of a single node trying to start.  So really, *any* node can be a seed node.  You could have a 3 node cluster, with A using C as a seed, and B using A as a seed.  Maybe C dies and has to be replaced (needs data), so it gets edited and uses B as a seed.  Now all of your nodes are seed nodes to at least one node, but not to all.  Point being; knowing that a node is a seed is not enough, because it only makes sense when asking "from which node is it a seed?"

Comment: In my example of a 5 members cluster, A and B being SEED to C, D and E, is it not mandatory to start the cluster following the A-B-C-D-E order ?

Comment: You only need to start A or B first and then the order doesn't matter. Once these nodes are up for first time, they can be restarted in any order later.

Answer (score 2):

Until Cassandra 4 is released with **nodetool getseeds** (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14190 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11406) it looks like the only way is to get the info is from cassandra.yaml

Your onliner seems to work, though it is limited to eth0